# Oracle division problem

Tags: oracle

I have this query :

```
select (round(scp.qty/ppc.qty) * 100,4) || '%' as qtyco from .....
```

The problem is that instead of returning "0.123 %" it returns just ".123 %"

Any ideea why..or how could i fix this?
the types of the two qty columns are NUMBER(12,0)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is just a display issue: your number is converted to a varchar since you're using the `||` concatenation operator (Oracle performs the conversion *implicitely*). You should ask for a format *explicitely*, for example:

```
select to_char(round(scp.qty / ppc.qty * 100, 4), 'fm990.9999') || '%' as qtyco
```

Answer (score 1):

Oracle can convert the number to char automatically. I think it would be better to convert it manually, so you would have control how to do it.